# how to stimulate a lowerpass filter in simulink?

Tags: simulink

I should stimulate how the lowpass filter work exactly with simulink so i create a signal  generator f=50 hz and i make a lowerfilter and after that i want to see it so the only tool that i found it is spectrum analyzer but when i simulate i get two errors 
Sorry if it's not really explain because i'm beginner in simulink 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signals being fed into the Spectrum Scope blocks need to be discrete-time signals instead of continuous-time. You can accomplish this by adding a [Zero-Order Hold](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/zeroorderhold.html) block before each Spectrum Scope, setting the desired discrete sample time in the Zero-Order Hold block's dialog parameters.

As a heads up, you're probably going to want to buffer your signals as well (the spectrum is calculated on "frames" of data, which you can read about here: [Create Frame-Based Signals](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/create-frame-based-signals.html)). To do this, you can either use a [Buffer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/buffer.html) block in between your Zero-Order Hold and Spectrum Scope, or select "Buffer Input" in the Spectrum Scope dialog parameters.

Comment: @PasstissiPhone: My mistake. The error is indicating that your S-Function (the Lowpass filter block) requires a discrete signal as well. Please move the Zero-Order Hold before the Lowpass Filter.